# Create a "Shared With" column for CURRENT permissioned users?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions, column

I know this must have been asked before, but I can't find it anywhere on StackExchange.

So the OOTB "Shared With" column shows a historical view of all users (current or past) who have ever had access to a document. And that is the intended function, according to MSFT. Interesting I guess...but absolutely useless for my purposes. There doesn't seem to be a column that shows current users with access to a doc/folder etc. Is there any way to create one?
I thought of a calculated column, checked through SP Designer for some kind of hack, but there doesn't seem to be any way of grabbing that data.

Help?